# How to access text from a webpage where url does not change after choosing a dropdown value?

Tags: php, html, beautifulsoup

I have a website - http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=texte

Upon selecting a text from the dropdown menu, the text appears on screen but the url does not update.

How do I get this text using beautiful soup?

Comment: It would be helpful to paste the relevant javascript code to stack overflow

Comment: Don't link to your website. Remove the link and add the relevant code to the stackoverflow question

Answer (score 0):

When you select a dropdown on that website it makes a request to a separate url to get the data.  If you make similar requests to those urls you'll get the data you are trying to gather.

```
curl 'http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/ajax-php/ajax-text-handler-wrapper.php' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=r864nj78198tr9ukeg8nuulkg0' -H 'Origin: http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=texte' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'mode=printsentences&chapterid=7032' --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of the webpage I can see you're using AJAX to load content. If you want to change the URL then you either have to navigate to a new URL using `window.location` or use history rewrite:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Keep in mind that you will need to add some additional hooks so that when the user navigates forward and back, your javascript reloads the content of the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API